# Sacar promedio de cada una de las filas de un arreglo multidimensional C++

Tags: c++, array

Estas son las instrucciones del programa:

> 1. El programa preguntará cuántos alumnos hay en el grupo y cuántos
>      conceptos se van a evaluar.
> 2. El programa pedirá las calificaciones de cada uno de los
>      estudiantes.
> 3. Al finalizar, el programa calculará y mostrará el promedio de cada
>      alumno y el promedio general del grupo.

Nada más tengo problemas al momento de sacar el promedio ya que todo lo que he intentado no funciona. Este es el código que he realizado:

```
using namespace std;

int main (){
    int matriz [100][100];
    double alumnos;
    double conceptos;
    int suma;
    double promedio;
    int contador=0;

    cout<<"BIENVENIDO A LA CALCULADORA DE PROMEDIOS";
    cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de alumnos: ";
    cin>>alumnos;
    cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de conceptos: ";
    cin>>conceptos;

    //Almacenando calificaciones
    for (int i=0; i<alumnos;i++){
        for (int j=0; j<conceptos;j++){
            cout<<"\nDigite la calificacion del alumno "<<i+1<<" en el concepto " << j+1<<": ";
            cin>>matriz[i][j];

        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<alumnos;i++){
        for (int j=0; j<conceptos;j++){
            suma=suma+ matriz[i][j];

        }
    }


}
```

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda para hacer un ciclo que saque los promedios de cada una de las filas (alumnos).

Comment: Sugerencia: Cuando digas que no funciona, procura incluir un detalle de lo que debería pasar y lo que no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es la solución que encontré:
en el 2do bucle for calculé el promedio por alumnos que almacené en la variable 'matriz_promedio', también en el mismo bucle for sumé todos los promedios y los almacené en la variable 'suma' y por último sumaba 1 al contador. Entonces en el 3er bucle for solo mostré los promedios y al final mostré el promedio de todos los alumnos

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
int matriz [100][100];
double matriz_promedio [100];
double alumnos;
double conceptos;
int suma;
double promedio;
int contador=0;

cout<<"BIENVENIDO A LA CALCULADORA DE PROMEDIOS";
cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de alumnos: ";
cin>>alumnos;
cout<<"\nIngrese el numero de conceptos: ";
cin>>conceptos;

//Almacenando calificaciones
for (int i=0; i<alumnos;i++){
    for (int j=0; j<conceptos;j++){
        cout<<"\nDigite la calificacion del alumno "<<i+1<<" en el concepto " << j+1<<": ";
        cin>>matriz[i][j];

    }
}

for (int i=0; i<alumnos;i++){
    for (int j=0; j<conceptos;j++){
        suma=suma+ matriz[i][j];
    }
    matriz_promedio[i] = (double)suma/conceptos;
    suma=0;
}

for (int x=0; x<alumnos;x++){
        cout<<"\nLos promedios del alumno "<<x+1<<" es" << ": "<<matriz_promedio[x];
        promedio += matriz_promedio[x];
        contador++;
    } 

cout<<"\nEl promedio total es:  "<<promedio/contador;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Y para este código en “Lenguaje C”

el código fuente de un programa donde se utilicen arreglos, apuntadores y funciones para:

1. Dar opción al usuario de registrar los alumnos que requiera (máx . 30). Leer de cada alumno su: número de cuenta, edad y calificación.
2. Calcular e imprimir el promedio del grupo
3. Calcular e imprimir la edad promedio de los alumnos del grupo cuya calificación sea igual o mayor a 6.0
4. Imprimir la lista completa del grupo incluyendo: Número de cuenta, edad y calificación

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Esto no responde a la pregunta: si tienes una nueva por hacer, [formúlala](/questions/ask), leyendo [ask] y teniendo en cuenta que [aquí no hacemos tareas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320), por lo tanto, demuestra lo que has hecho hasta el momento :)